# Raspberry Pi SSH Access Denied

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

I am trying to log into my Raspberry Pi using [PuTTY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY) from Windows. However, whenever I try to log into my Raspberry Pi using the default username and password (pi* and *raspberry*) it says *Access Denied*.

I have the *wpa_supplicant.conf* file and ssh file created. This is its first bootup. I am using the latest version of the Raspbian Lite OS.

Comment: *Raspain* might be a fitting name...

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Recently, the default user setup of Raspbian was significantly changed, rendering most existing online tutorials invalid.

In essence, the default `pi` user no longer exists, so you have to create it and set its password using either the official [Imager](https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/) tool or by creating a `userconf` file in the `boot` partition of your microSD card, which should contain a single line of text: `username:hashed-password`, replacing `username` with the name of the user you want (e.g., `pi`) and `hashed-password` with the hash of the password you want.

According to the official guide, the easiest way to do this is by running the following in a terminal (Linux or macOS):

```
echo 'password' | openssl passwd -6 -stdin
```

Again, you should replace `password` with the password you want here.

Further reading: *[An update to Raspberry Pi OS Bullseye](https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/raspberry-pi-bullseye-update-april-2022/)* (2022-04-07)

Comment: Default `pi` and `raspberry`: `pi:$6$/4.VdYgDm7RJ0qM1$FwXCeQgDKkqrOU3RIRuDSKpauAbBvP11msq9X58c8Que2l1Dwq3vdJMgiZlQSbEXGaY5esVHGBNbCxKLVNqZW1`

Comment: I can't believe their Official User Guide hasn't been updated...

Comment: Thanks @AndréKuhlmann I love you

Comment: @nmu you are welcome, but credit goes out to the following post: https://discourse.pi-hole.net/t/warning-latest-raspberry-pi-os-image-april-4th-2022/54778

Comment: Unfortunately for me Imager 1.7.3 either filled in the wrong hash for the password or did not generate the `firstboot.sh` at all. I had to go with the manual way of creating the `boot/userconf` file and populating it with `user:password_hash`.

Answer (score 10):

The default username and password are no longer valid for Raspberry Pi.

If you are trying to log in headlessly (without a monitor and keyboard), you can do it from [Raspberry Pi Imager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi_OS#Versions) itself.
On *selecting* the OS in Raspberry Pi Imager, you get an icon of **settings** in which you can

- create a user
- setup Wi-Fi
- enable SSH

After configuring, you can continue flashing your *memory card*.
And on first boot you will be good to go.

Comment: How does the Imager tool actually change the username and password? I'm vaguely aware that it puts a "firstboot" script, so I'm guessing that's where it adds users, but how does it actually write that firstboot script to the filesystem and configure it to run when the system boots?

Answer (score 3):

I have solved this problem. You can easily input your username and password with [Raspberry Pi Imager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi_OS#Versions).

[image: Screenshot of an example of using "Advanced Options" in Raspberry Pi Imager]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You should embed that image, and tell us how to reach that settings menu.

Comment: this helped me... the correct aswer didn't work for me

Comment: The hope for improvement is dwindling - *"Last seen more than a week ago"*

Comment: Without improvement, this answer is essentially a screenshot for the previous two answers.

Comment: **2023 update**  this solution works FINE!

Answer (score 3):

### A simpler solution only needs one step.

> Create a file named `userconf.txt` with your PC / Mac, and drop it into your `SD card` root folder after you write the `Raspberry Pi OS` image system.

```
pi:/4g6TptuTP5B6
```

> demo

[image]

### test

```bash
# check ✅
$ cat /boot/userconf.txt
pi:/4g6TptuTP5B6
```

[image]

### refs

https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html#configuring-a-user

Comment: Be nice if they loaded the defaults into the F'ing image!  That worked.  Thanks  And someone should move this to the top!

Answer (score 1):

add the user you created when flashing the image to the ssh group.

```
 usermod -a -G ssh YourPiUsername
```

Comment: Still did not help me

Comment: membership in ssh group seems not to be necessary for a user. mine isn't in ssh and I can connect via ssh with it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to ssh to your raspberry pi with its username and ip address like below.

```
ssh username@192.1xx.x.x
```

I had made the mistake of assuming my username was pi and the ip address can just be represented with hostname "raspberrypi".

```
ssh pi@raspberrypi
```

Which is wrong. Hope this help.